# Access-Control-Allow-Origin null value for WKWebView - Restrict to local file ONLY

Tags: ios, http-headers, cors, wkwebview

I have a common web service used by a web application (internet browser access) and by a mobile app.

My iOS app loads a local html file in a WKWebView and calls this web service using javascript/ajax so as per new CORS implementation in WKWebView I must add an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the response. I will add this header only when coming from the app and not when coming from a web browser - for security reasons.

If I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * everything works as expected. However I would prefer to prevent the access from anything but a local page. I have tried to set it as null and it does not work in WKWebView - but it is working if I open a local html page in Firefox that makes the ajax call.

Is is possible to achieve this in WKWebView? I have only found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7348 where the person said "The only solution is, the destination server MUST return the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" that matches the wildcard or "null"" but it is not working on my side (iOS 10/11)